# Cannot start jenkins server with Java-11

Tags: jenkins, service, centos, centos7, java-11

I'm upgrading Jenkins on Centos7

I upgraded it to the latest successfully (Yum upgrade Jenkins)

The service starts fine with java-8 but with java-11 it won't start

**Getting the error:** failed (Result: start-limit)

**Java version that I used:** java-11-openjdk-11.0.15.0.9-2.el7_9.x86_64

**The error on startup:**

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:252)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.finish(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:198)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.onEvent(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:213)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.EPollPort$EventHandlerTask.run(EPollPort.java:306)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Which version of Jenkins do you use? have you read https://www.jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/upgrade-java-guidelines/

Comment: Hey @Robert I use the 2.346.2 Jenkins version and I followed this guide for upgrade

Comment: Then you should check the log file(s) for errors. Without more details it is difficult to guess what is going wrong.

Comment: Added some logs @Robert